# Android calendar app made with swipeable fragments

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-calendar

I am trying to make a calendar inside a project, and I want it to be with swipeable fragments. So currently I am having an adapter for the swipeable tabs

```
public class FragmentTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public FragmentTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = null;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return ("January");
        case 1:
            return ("February");
        case 2:
            return ("March");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

And this is Fragment1 (other 2 are identidcal)

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public Fragment1() {
        // Empty constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        Calendar mMonth = Calendar.getInstance();
        gridview.setAdapter(new CalendarAdapter(getActivity(), mMonth));
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

and this is the code with which the Calendar gets populated, using grid view

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    TextView dayView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.calendar_item, null);
    }
    v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int) Math.ceil((parent.getWidth() / 7)), (int) Math.ceil((parent.getWidth() / 7))));
    dayView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
    dayView.setText(days[position].toString());
    dayView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    if (days[position].getMonth() - 1 != month.get(Calendar.MONTH) || days[position].getYear() != month.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
        dayView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(154, 154, 154));
    } else {
        if (days[position].hasEvent()) {
            if (days[position].getIsSelected()) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        } else {
            if (days[position].getIsSelected()) {
                dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

What I want to know is, if its possible to make a fully functional calendar using only 3 fragments, and they to be recycled as the user swipes to the sides, so he can go to any date without the need to have 100 fragments each for different month. How can I do this?

Comment: Just use the same `Fragment` class and pass the current `Date` to the `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the `Date` to the same `Fragment` class. Normally a static factory method is used for this. I modified your `Fragment` accordingly:

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String EXTRA_DATE = "date";

    // With this method you can create a new Instance of this
    // ExampleFragment. The Date is passed to the Fragment
    // through a Bundle
    public static Fragment newInstance(Date date) {
        ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();

        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putSerializable(EXTRA_DATE, date);
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);

        return fragment;
    }

    private GridView gridView;
    private Date date;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        this.gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Here we retrieve the Date from the Bundle
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if(arguments != null) {
            this.date = (Date) arguments.getSerializable(EXTRA_DATE);
            // Do whatever you want with the Date
        }
    }
}
```

So with this `ExampleFragment` your `Adapter` would look like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    int yearsToAdd = position / 12;

    // Here we create a Date based on the position, 
    // We set the Date to be at the start of each month
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, yearsToAdd);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, position);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Date date = calendar.getTime();

    // Here we return a new instance of the ExampleFragment
    // And pass along the Date from above
    return ExampleFragment.newInstance(date);
}
```

Comment: return ExampleFragment.newInstance(date);
what is this newInstance method? I dont have it, only got instantiate, and it requires context

Comment: Did you even look at my code? Its right there I defined it.

Comment: sorry I missed few lines, let me check again

Comment: what about this method in the fragments pager adapter?
@Override
 public int getCount() {
  return 0;
 }

Comment: That just determines how many months into the future you want to display, you can put anything there.

Comment: so just put 100 for example? doubt the user would want to see anything beyond that, and it dont affect the memory right?

Comment: No it does not, that's the point of a `ViewPager` and `Adapter`. Fragments which are out of screen are recycled.